# Sorting through many files and unzipping them at once

Tags: python

I have a program that currently unzips files in a specific folder. However, I have many files in t that need to be sorted through. In my trades folder there are many coins and each coin has many files. I can get the files in each coin but cannot go through the folders initially for each coin. I need to be able to go through all those files without manually changing the directory to each coin.
[This is how the files are set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcYe3.png)

```
import os
import zipfile

dir_name = 'E:/binance-public-data/python/data/spot/monthly/trades'
extension = ".zip"

for item in os.listdir(dir_name): 
    if item.endswith(extension):
        file_name = os.path.abspath(item)
        zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(file_name)
        zip_ref.extractall(dir_name)
        zip_ref.close()
        os.remove(file_name)
```

Comment: I imported os but forgot to show that

Comment: Where do you want to extract the files to? I assume you have zip files in each of the directories you show. What directory paths are in the zipfiles themselves?

Comment: What goes wrong with the script you posted?

Comment: I want to just extract them where they are. The problem is that since the files in trades are not zips they are folders the scirpt doesn't do anything to them. What I need is the script to go into the folders which has the files that need to be unzipped. Like trades->any coin-> unzip->exit and go to next folder-> repeat

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.listdir` gives you the file name in the directory. You would have to rebuild its path from your current directory before accessing the file. `os.path.abspath(item)` created an absolute path from your current working directory, not the directory holding your zip file.

You can use `glob` instead. It will filter out non-zip file extensions and will keep the relative path to the found file so you don't have to fiddle with the path. The `pathlib` module makes path handling a bit easier than `glob.glob` and `os.path`, so I'll use it here.

```
import zipfile
from pathlib import Path

dir_name = Path('E:/binance-public-data/python/data/spot/monthly/trades')
extension = ".zip"

for file_name in dir_name.glob("*/*" + extension): 
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_name) as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall(file_name.parent)
    file_name.unlink()
```

Comment: I did it, I removed the period you put after */*

Comment: Good eye. Fixed.